# how to use complexity-report tool on a js project

Tags: javascript, npm, code-complexity, jsperf, npmjs

I have installed [complexity-report](https://www.npmjs.com/package/complexity-report) on a javascript project

Instalation is done using ***$ npm install complexity-report*** on the root directory of the project. I can run ***$ cr*** and it shows some configuration options like on the image above [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ovjy.png).

What i don't know is which command i have to use or what steps i have to follow to calculate for example the complexity of a specific js folder?

I need some help with a description of how to use this tool. Some explanations of that tool are given [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/complexity-report) but i don't understand which is the next step to follow in my case.

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried npm cr?

Comment: `cr path/to/root/of/code` That will create a report like https://github.com/escomplex/complexity-report/blob/master/EXAMPLE.md I'm unsure which part you don't understand. Are you asking for an explanation of all the options?

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding @Juan. How to exclude for example the folder node_modules from complexity calculating? Is it ok if i use command **cr -x node_modules path/of/the/directory/to/calculate**  ?

Comment: I'm sure it's OK, not sure if it will work :p Did you try it?

Comment: yes it is ok. Thanks